# Purescript 0.12 Getting Started

Tags: purescript

i`m trying to run the very basic flow:

1) install tools:

> npm install -g pulp bower

Pulp version 12.2.0
purs version 0.12.0 using C:\Users\panda.psvm\current\bin\purs.EXE
C:\Users\panda>bower --version
1.8.4

2) following steps from this answer i installed purs https://stackoverflow.com/a/50554135/1358421

C:\Users\panda>purs --version
0.12.0

Ok, lets create a project.

> c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr>mkdir hello-purr
>
> c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr>cd hello-purr
>
> c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr\hello-purr>
>   pulp init

```
c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr\hello-purr>pulp init
* Generating project skeleton in c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr\hello-purr
bower purescript-console#*      cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-console.git#4.1.0
bower purescript-console#*    validate 4.1.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-console.git#*
bower purescript-prelude#*      cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude.git#4.0.0
bower purescript-prelude#*    validate 4.0.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude.git#*
bower purescript-prelude#^4.0.0 cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude.git#4.0.0
bower purescript-prelude#^4.0.0         validate 4.0.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude.git#^4.0.0
bower purescript-effect#^2.0.0            cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-effect.git#2.0.0
bower purescript-effect#^2.0.0          validate 2.0.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-effect.git#^2.0.0
bower purescript-console#^4.1.0          install purescript-console#4.1.0
bower purescript-prelude#^4.0.0          install purescript-prelude#4.0.0
bower purescript-effect#^2.0.0           install purescript-effect#2.0.0

purescript-console#4.1.0 bower_components\purescript-console
├── purescript-effect#2.0.0
└── purescript-prelude#4.0.0

purescript-prelude#4.0.0 bower_components\purescript-prelude

purescript-effect#2.0.0 bower_components\purescript-effect
└── purescript-prelude#4.0.0
bower purescript-psci-support#* cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-psci-support.git#4.0.0
bower purescript-psci-support#*         validate 4.0.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-psci-support.git#*
bower purescript-psci-support#^4.0.0     install purescript-psci-support#4.0.0

purescript-psci-support#4.0.0 bower_components\purescript-psci-support
├── purescript-console#4.1.0
├── purescript-effect#2.0.0
└── purescript-prelude#4.0.0
```

Skeleton of project successfully generated.

Trying to run it:

> pulp run

```
* Building project in c:\home\projects\sandbox\purr\hello-purr
Error 1 of 2:

  in module Main
  at src\Main.purs line 4, column 1 - line 4, column 31

    Module Control.Monad.Eff was not found.
    Make sure the source file exists, and that it has been provided as an input to the compiler.


  See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ModuleNotFound.md for more information,
  or to contribute content related to this error.

Error 2 of 2:

  in module Main
  at src\Main.purs line 5, column 1 - line 5, column 48

    Module Control.Monad.Eff.Console was not found.
    Make sure the source file exists, and that it has been provided as an input to the compiler.


  See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ModuleNotFound.md for more information,
  or to contribute content related to this error.


* ERROR: Subcommand terminated with exit code 1
```

No luck :(

> pulp test
>   pulp build

The same errors - It can`t find modules.
Did i miss something? Please, advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purescript 0.12 pulls in newer versions of the Effect and Console libraries, unfortunately pulp init has not yet been updated to correct the generated example to match (see https://github.com/purescript-contrib/pulp/issues/337)

just update the code in Main.purs to:

```
module Main where

import Prelude (Unit)
import Effect
import Effect.Console (log)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  log "Hello sailor!"`
```

to get started.

Comment: also, i realized that 'pulp init' makes bower download outdated libraries, that not working with purescript 12 anymore

Comment: try again with a fresh folder:

`npm install -g purescript pulp bower`

then

`pulp init`

edit the Main.purs to above.

*then* `pulp run`

that works for me

Comment: yeah, works ) Its so messy, when you doing first steps right after the language or framework has been released with breaking changes..

Comment: yeah I had the same issue, managed to pick a really bad moment to try the quick start :) Hopefully it will all be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

1. don't need bower at all
2. instead, there is a psc-package (another package manager)
3. it didn't installed correctly on my Windows 10 with `npm install -g psc-package`

there was no psc-package.exe file in directory `${username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\psc-package\vendor`
So, you need to fix install.js file and replace

```
ignore: ['psc-package']
```

with

```
ignore: [bin.use()]
```

then run fixed installation with

```
${username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\psc-package\lib> node install
```

after that, In the `vendor` folder you may find psc-package.exe

Then, i followed this tutorial: 
https://github.com/justinwoo/purescript-0.12.0-hello-world 
and

```
Build successful.
look, show on Record:
{ apple: "banana" }
```